# How to group data when data are interspersed with group headers in the same column?

Tags: r, data.table

Basically, my data is grouped by days with an inconsistent number of rows in between:

```
16-Oct-16
Name1
Name2
Name3
17-Oct-16
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4
Name5
19-Oct-16
```

etc.

I need to be able to grab the group data and apply it to the child records.
The expected result should look as follows:

```
Name1   16-Oct-16
Name2   16-Oct-16
Name3   16-Oct-16
Name1   17-Oct-16
Name2   17-Oct-16
Name3   17-Oct-16
Name4   17-Oct-16
Name5   17-Oct-16
```

I'm using `data.table` but currently I can't think of any way other than a loop.

The following script generates the kind of dataset I'm looking at:

```
data.table(c('October 16, 2016', paste0('Name',1:4),
             'October 17, 2016', paste0('Name',1:12),
             'October 20, 2016', paste0('Name',1:2),
             'October 25, 2016', paste0('Name',1:6)))
```

I just want to copy the appropriate date field to each name row and end up with a tidy dataset where each row has name and date.

Comment: How do you get this data at first in real worlds ? This sounds like àwk`could be the perfect tool to arrange your dataset before loading it into R

Comment: Could you please be more precise in your example data and what your expected outcome is? For guielines on how to improve your question, see [ask] and [how to give a  reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example would help.

Comment: The sample data you are showing and the script to generate them should be consistent. Now, they are using two different date formats.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `data.table` solution I have used in similar situations. (I've tested with `data.table` version 1.9.7. but it should work also with the CRAN version 1.9.6)

## Read Data

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("16-Oct-16
            Name1
            Name2
            Name3
            17-Oct-16
            Name1
            Name2
            Name3
            Name4
            Name5
            19-Oct-16",
            header = FALSE)
print(dt)
           V1
 1: 16-Oct-16
 2:     Name1
 3:     Name2
 4:     Name3
 5: 17-Oct-16
 6:     Name1
 7:     Name2
 8:     Name3
 9:     Name4
10:     Name5
11: 19-Oct-16
```

## Last observation carried forward

The group headers are dates. So I used the `dmy` function of the `lubridate` package to coerce them to date format where possible. For lines which aren't formatted as dates `dmy` creates `NA`. Using `na.locf` from package `zoo` the last non-NA observation is carried forward. Both operations can be combined in a one-liner:

```
dt[, day := zoo::na.locf(lubridate::dmy(V1))]
print(dt)
           V1        day
 1: 16-Oct-16 2016-10-16
 2:     Name1 2016-10-16
 3:     Name2 2016-10-16
 4:     Name3 2016-10-16
 5: 17-Oct-16 2016-10-17
 6:     Name1 2016-10-17
 7:     Name2 2016-10-17
 8:     Name3 2016-10-17
 9:     Name4 2016-10-17
10:     Name5 2016-10-17
11: 19-Oct-16 2016-10-19
```

(I guess there is a faster version using rolling joins instead of `na.locf`.)

## Remove group header lines

To remove the group headers we need to keep a temporary column.

```
dt[, tmp := lubridate::dmy(V1)][, day := zoo::na.locf(tmp)]
print(dt)
           V1        tmp        day
 1: 16-Oct-16 2016-10-16 2016-10-16
 2:     Name1       <NA> 2016-10-16
 3:     Name2       <NA> 2016-10-16
 4:     Name3       <NA> 2016-10-16
 5: 17-Oct-16 2016-10-17 2016-10-17
 6:     Name1       <NA> 2016-10-17
 7:     Name2       <NA> 2016-10-17
 8:     Name3       <NA> 2016-10-17
 9:     Name4       <NA> 2016-10-17
10:     Name5       <NA> 2016-10-17
11: 19-Oct-16 2016-10-19 2016-10-19

dt <- dt[is.na(tmp)]
print(dt)
      V1  tmp        day
1: Name1 <NA> 2016-10-16
2: Name2 <NA> 2016-10-16
3: Name3 <NA> 2016-10-16
4: Name1 <NA> 2016-10-17
5: Name2 <NA> 2016-10-17
6: Name3 <NA> 2016-10-17
7: Name4 <NA> 2016-10-17
8: Name5 <NA> 2016-10-17

dt[, tmp := NULL]
print(dt)
      V1        day
1: Name1 2016-10-16
2: Name2 2016-10-16
3: Name3 2016-10-16
4: Name1 2016-10-17
5: Name2 2016-10-17
6: Name3 2016-10-17
7: Name4 2016-10-17
8: Name5 2016-10-17
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use a regex pattern. For the first example dataset:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
dt1[grep('([0-9]{1,2})-([A-Za-z]+)-(\\d{2})', V1), V2 := V1
    ][, V2 := na.locf(V2)][V1!=V2]
```

which gives:

```
      V1        V2
1: Name1 16-Oct-16
2: Name2 16-Oct-16
3: Name3 16-Oct-16
4: Name1 17-Oct-16
5: Name2 17-Oct-16
6: Name3 17-Oct-16
7: Name4 17-Oct-16
8: Name5 17-Oct-16
```

For the second dataset, you can use:

```
dt2[grep('([A-Za-z]+ )([0-9]{1,2}[,] )(\\d{4})', V1), V2 := V1
    ][, V2 := na.locf(V2)][V1!=V2]
```

which gives:

```
        V1               V2
 1:  Name1 October 16, 2016
 2:  Name2 October 16, 2016
 3:  Name3 October 16, 2016
 4:  Name4 October 16, 2016
 5:  Name1 October 17, 2016
 6:  Name2 October 17, 2016
 7:  Name3 October 17, 2016
 8:  Name4 October 17, 2016
 9:  Name5 October 17, 2016
10:  Name6 October 17, 2016
11:  Name7 October 17, 2016
12:  Name8 October 17, 2016
13:  Name9 October 17, 2016
14: Name10 October 17, 2016
15: Name11 October 17, 2016
16: Name12 October 17, 2016
17:  Name1 October 20, 2016
18:  Name2 October 20, 2016
19:  Name1 October 25, 2016
20:  Name2 October 25, 2016
21:  Name3 October 25, 2016
22:  Name4 October 25, 2016
23:  Name5 October 25, 2016
24:  Name6 October 25, 2016
```

---

Used data:

```
dt1 <- fread("16-Oct-16
             Name1
             Name2
             Name3
             17-Oct-16
             Name1
             Name2
             Name3
             Name4
             Name5
             19-Oct-16", header = FALSE)
```

and:

```
dt2 <- data.table(c('October 16, 2016', paste0('Name',1:4),
                    'October 17, 2016', paste0('Name',1:12),
                    'October 20, 2016', paste0('Name',1:2),
                    'October 25, 2016', paste0('Name',1:6)))
```